# Map a large DTO to reactive form in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a plain DTO from service having multiple properties (order of 100s). I want to map these properties in an angular reactive form and update the original DTO once the form is saved.

Only few values of these DTOs are updated by form. However the reactive form can rearrange the arrays.
I have to create a full copy of DTO by mapping each properties and array as `FormControl` and `ForArray` in the reactive from.

I want to know if it is possible to make it simpler, as all of it seems a bit unnecessary but still it is required.

Answer (score 0):

just a sugestion: If you say that only few fields will be updated, you can use a dropdownlist with the fields (from where you select the field which need to be updated), and an input field for the new value, and a table with two columns "field" and "newValue" where you add line for every updated field.

Then, save it as a key/value pair (where key is the updated field name).

I see this like a good optimization.